# Vue.js - Why should I put images on /assets instead of putting them directly in /public

Tags: vue.js, vue-cli

When I use the **@vue/cli** to create a vuejs project, I see that there is a folder `/assets` that contains images and whatever I want. Than they can be referenced in the html such as `<img src="@/assets/images/home.png" />` or import it on the js part.

My question is, why can't I just put the assets in `/public/assets` and put directly `<img src="/assets/images/home.png" />` in my code? Where is the advantage of these assets?

Comment: See [*The `public` Folder*](https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/html-and-static-assets.html#the-public-folder) and [*When to use the `public` folder*](https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/html-and-static-assets.html#when-to-use-the-public-folder)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It allows Webpack to handle assets, which means it can merge/minify files (useful for JS and CSS), optimize images, and more importantly version them so that cache handling is improved.